# Denesting of sum of multiple square roots

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algorithms

It was well known that a nested radical with form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{q}}$ can be "denested" if and only if either $a^2-b^2q$ or $q(b^2q-a^2)$ is a square.

However, I can't make any generalization of the above result. For example, consider a more complex nested radical $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{p}+c\sqrt{q}+d\sqrt{pq}}$. I tried to find some formulas like the $a^2-b^2q$ above which can be easily computed and used to test the existence of a possible denesting, but without any success.

I am aware that the denesting problem should in general be decidable and there is a general algorithm which in theory should be able to answer whether denesting is possible for any nested radical, but such a general algorithm is over complicated and I can't find any concrete implementation of it.

I'm mostly interested in denesting square roots of sums of square roots, that is, nested radicals with the form $$\sqrt{\sum_i{a_i\sqrt{q_i}}}$$ or particularly, nested radicals with the form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{p}+c\sqrt{q}+d\sqrt{pq}}$ (which can be regarded as a direct generalization of the well-known form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{q}}$). And **I would like to know if there exists some quantities which are reasonably computable functions** of $a_i$ and $q_i$ (or, in particular, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $p$ and $q$ in the four-term form) **and can be used to determine the existence of a possible denesting**.

The tests and conditions do not have to be necessary and sufficient at the same time. A sufficient test which covers a reasonably large range of all denesting possibilities is also welcomed.

Comment: Your quantity is $\sqrt{\alpha + \gamma\sqrt q}$, where $\alpha = a + b\sqrt p$ and $\gamma = c + d\sqrt p$ lie in $k(\sqrt p)$.  Doesn't that show that it can be denested if and only if $\alpha^2 - \gamma^2q$ or $-q(\alpha^2 - \gamma^2q)$ is a square in $k(\sqrt p)$?

Comment: For denesting where the only roots involved are square roots, you don't need the general algorithm. If I'm reading the documentation correctly, [Sympy handles the square root case](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html?highlight=sqrtdenest#module-sympy.simplify.sqrtdenest) - or, certainly, the first reference given in the documentation claims to be complete for denesting the square root of a sum of square roots.

Comment: A numerical approach: A real number is algebraic of degree $2$ if and only if its continued fraction expansion is ultimately periodic.